# How to detect home activity is launched in android?

Tags: android, homescreen, android-launcher

How to detect home activity is launched/displayed using package info.
like we get package name by this code:

```
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo localRunningTaskInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo)((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService("activity")).getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
String str1 = localRunningTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
String str2 = localRunningTaskInfo.topActivity.getClassName();
```

With this we get all applications package name and class name. how to detect home is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get this. Following is the sample code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


 // get the info from the currently running task
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

 Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

[Example Project](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/)

From logcat you can see the which activity is lanched..

Comment: how to check if its home launcher package name like if(packageName.equals(HOME_ACTIVITY_PACKAGE)){}

Comment: @yuva if you get activity name in log then store that in string and compare with that.

Comment: logcat reading is not supported in  android 4.1 and up. that's why i need package name of home launcher.how can i get it for different devices. its different for different devices.

Comment: @yuva i have checked v4.2.2 device it worked for me.. i am getting result like this.. com.example.gallerypopup.MainActivity

Comment: i done want applications launcher activity.i want package name when i press home button on device we get home screen that package name not specific activity name

Comment: like on emulator after pressing home button in logcat i'm getting package name as com.android.launcher.its only for emulator and different for other devices.

Comment: @yuva now i check it it coming.

Comment: You are not getting my question.according to you i'm getting all package name.also package name for home launcher.how can i check its package for home screen.its different for different devices.